# Passing parameters during refresh portlet

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet

I have a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Liferay.Portlet.refresh('#p_p_id_myPortletName_')">link_name</a>
```

It works good, my portlet is being refreshed, but I also need to pass other variables (parameters) along with portlet id to refresh with based on passed params.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create render url and make ajax call to reload portlet content.

In view.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>
<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="reloadPortletURL" copyCurrentRenderParameters="true" portletMode="<%=LiferayPortletMode.VIEW.toString() %>"
    windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.NORMAL.toString()%>">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="param1" value="Param1"/>
    <liferay-portlet:param name="param2" value="Param2"/>
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>

<a href="#" onclick="ajaxCall('${reloadPortletURL}')">Reload portlet</a>
```

And js function:

```
function ajaxCall(url){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#p_p_id_myPortletName_').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Liferay.Portlet.refresh(portlet, data)` method has two arguments.
You can look at `/ROOT/html/js/liferay/portlet.js` for refresh method implementation.

portlet : It is portlet id

data : This object will be treated as form data when it send ajax request

```
function refreshPortlet(portletId, param1, param2){

    var data = {'param1':param1,'param2':param2};

    Liferay.Portlet.refresh(portletId, data);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple work-arround would be to create custom wrapper method to which you can pass additional parameters and achieve whatever your requirement is before calling to `Liferay.Portlet.refresh`, as following:

**function call:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="refreshPortlet('#p_p_id_myPortletName_', 'param1', 'param2');">link_name</a>
```

**function definition:**

```
function refreshPortlet(portletId, param1, param2){

    /* peform operations with other parameters here */

    Liferay.Portlet.refresh(portletId);
}
```